# How to test Interface Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
interface ITest
{
    void Run();
}

class Test : ITest
{
    void ITest.Run() => Run();
    public int Run()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Hello, how to verify that ITest.Run() execute "Run" of Test?

Comment: You could make use of the `Run` return value, or you could print something, of you could debug... there are multiple ways to do that...

Comment: I want to do anything like mock.Verify(m=> m.Run(), Times.Once());
But I don't understand how I can do this.

Comment: This depends on the mocking Framework that you use. So could you please state which you are currently using?

Comment: Moq, but I can't replace non-virtual methods by moq

Answer (score 1):

You *could* test this using a mocking framework like Moq:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Run();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    void ITest.Run() => Run();

    public virtual int Run()
    {
        return 1; // doesn’t matter, will be replaced by our mock
    }
}
```

The test would then look like this:

```
// arrange
Mock<Test> mock = new Mock<Test>();
mock.CallBase = true;
mock.Setup(t => t.Run()).Returns(1);

// act
ITest test = mock.Object;
test.Run();

// assert
mock.Verify(t => t.Run(), Times.Once());
```

This correctly throws when `ITest.Run` does not call the `Run` of `Test`. However, as you can see, doing this requires the `Run` method to be virtual so that the mock can overwrite it with its own implementation. This might not be desireable.

And ultimately, that test doesn’t does not make any sense. When you unit test something, you want to unit test the *behavior*, not the implementation. So it shouldn’t matter to you whether the explicit implementation `ITest.Run` calls another method on the object or not. You should only care about that the behavior of calling that method is correct.

Comment: But I can't make Run method as virtual

Comment: @Serg046 As I explained in my answer, there is no way to test the *class’s* `Test` method without making it virtual in this case, since otherwise the mock cannot override it. Note that the accepted answer does not test the `Test` class at all, but only tests the interface (and actually only tests that the mock that implements the interface calls the method when the method is called).

Answer (score 1):

To test interface is the easiest task!
You can simply do it with [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/) (no virtual methods needed), take a look:

```
 [TestMethod, Isolated]
 public void TestRun()
 {
    //Arrange
    var fake = Isolate.Fake.Instance<ITest>();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fake.Run()).CallOriginal();

    //Act
    fake.Run();

    //Assert
    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments(() => fake.Run());
}
```

You are mocking the interface, then setting the behavior to Run() method (it's optional), and after all you can verify the call was made.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not do anything useful. You are providing a fake/mock implementation of the interface, call the interface’s method and then check whether that exact method was called (which you explicitly did in the test). This does not test OP’s `Test` class at all.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to verify that Run is called unless your interface is used in another class. (not the class implementing it). So if you have a second class USING your ITest-interface, then it makes sense to verify that Run is called as you have done

Comment: I'm testing Test class (not ITest interface)